# ejecutar un .bat desde C# sin que se muestre la ventana de CMD

Tags: c#, batch

Estoy creando un `.exe` para correr un .jar, funciona, el unico problema es que muestra una ventana emergente(`CMD`) por unos milisegundos, hay alguna manera de hacer que esto no suceda?

Aqui mi codigo para ejecutar el `.bat`:

```
using System;

namespace Launch
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("start.bat");
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi `.bat`:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\START"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\START\jre8\bin\javaw.exe" -jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M START.jar
```

Otra manera que intente fue hacerlo todo desde `C#`(pero obtuve el mismo resultado):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Launch
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {           

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.Arguments = "-jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M START.jar";
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.FileName = "jre8\\bin\\javaw.exe";
            Process.Start(psi);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te hace falta definir el uso de una Shell (`UseShellExecute`) como falso, aquí está tu código junto con la línea que le hace falta:

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;  
 psi.Arguments = "-jar -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M START.jar";
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
 psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 psi.FileName = "jre8\\bin\\javaw.exe";
 Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: de nada bro, algo seguro que ya funcionará :D

Comment: una pregunta, es mi primer soft en `C#`, hay muchos tipos de proyectos, elegi el de linea de comandos `.NET`, es la mejor manera?

Comment: excelente :D revisa esta academia: https://mva.microsoft.com tiene un curso muy bueno sobre desarrollo desde cero con C#. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, depende del proyecto,para iniciar está perfecto, te ayuda a desarrollar lógica, de manera abstracta, la parte visual se integra a la lógica que tienes :)

Comment: Si, para programas que no necesitan UI y son comandos de texto esta bien.

Answer (score 1):

puedes:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:pepe.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

o

```
set objshell = createobject ("wscript.shell")
objshell.run "nombredetuarchivo.bat" , vbhide
```

o

```
Dim WinScriptHost Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Scheduled Jobs\mybat.bat" & Chr(34), 0 Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Comment: El lenguage de la pregunta es C# , sería mejor agregar esa versión del código.